# How do I add custom transformations to a PMML using R?

Tags: r, pmml

I am trying to add a function of two variables into a PMML in R.

The model I am trying to execute is

> y = a + b*exp(Sepal.Width - Sepal.Length)^2

And I want the input to the PMML to be Sepal.Width and Sepal.Length.

I have the following code to make field derived_Sepal.Length, but I can't figure out how to use a custom transformation function such as exp(Sepal.Width - Sepal.Length)^2.

```
library(pmml)
library(XML)
library(pmmlTransformations)
irisBox <- WrapData(iris)
irisBox <- ZScoreXform(irisBox,"Sepal.Length")

model <- lm(Petal.Width ~ derived_Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width, data=irisBox$data)
pmmlModel <- pmml(model,transforms=irisBox)

pmmlModelEnhanced <- addLT(pmmlModel,namespace="4_2")
saveXML(pmmlModelEnhanced, file=outputPMMLFilename)
```

Any general advice or tips on doing data transformations in PMML using R would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that arithmetic operators in R functions generally do not do arithmetic???

Comment: @BondedDust - No, and I'm not sure what you are referring to.  Do you have a link with additional information on this?

Comment: My comment was too terse. It was intended to refer only to how operators work in R formula objects. A minus sign in front of a variable name in a formula removes it from consideration in the regression call, and an up-caret-two `(.)^2` creates interaction terms for terms inside the parentheses but does _not_ cause values to be raised to the power of 2. You could start your self-education with `?formula`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no ready to use tools for transforming arbitrary R expressions to PMML. You will have to compose the PMML snippet manually using generic R XML API, and attach it to the PMML document before it is written to a file.

Let's assume that you want to use a derived field `my_field`:

```
my_field = (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width)^2
# Use the my_field in your formula
lm = lm(Species ~ my_field, data = iris)
# Convert the lm() object to an in-memory XML DOM object
lm.pmml = pmml(lm)
# Fix the contents of the PMML/DataDictionary:
# 1) Remove the 'my_field' field definition
# 2) Add `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` field definitions - you will be referencing them in your custom expression, so they need to be available
lm.pmml = remove_datafield(lm.pmml, "my_field")
lm.pmml = add_datafield(lm.pmml, "Sepal.Width", "double", "continuous")
lm.pmml = add_datafield(lm.pmml, "Sepal.Length", "double", "continuous")
# Fix the contents of the PMML/TransformationDictionary:
# 1) Add 'my_field' field definition
lm.pmml = add_derivedfield(lm.pmml, ..)
# The PMML manipulation is done now, save it to a local filesystem file
saveXML(lm.pmml, outputPMMLFilename)
```

Going forward, you might want to keep an eye on the [JPMML-Converter](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-converter) project, because the automated R to PMML translation is a planned feature there.

Comment: Your remove_datafield and add_datafield do not appear to be legal functions.  What I think you are suggesting it to modify the PMML using XML formatting to add the new functionality that I desire.  I'll try this.

Comment: Indeed, these two are totally made up function names. You should implement your own "utility library" for that. Also, I recommend you to take a look into the source code of `pmml` and `pmmlTransformations` packages to see how the XML manipulation is done.

Comment: It works to hand code the XML files.  Although R can't encode these transformations into PMML, my statistician producing the PMML claims that SAS can encode these transformations into the PMML.  He is going to look into this.  Long term we are going to try to move to SAS produced PMML files.